# What's wonky with this recent-reputation-change counter?

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar, achievements-dialog

I seldom look in the recent-reputation-changes page (achievements), and the counter just tends to build up. It was 4929 earlier today, and it seems to have abruptly dropped to 368:

[image]

At the top is Edge, open from this morning, showing the count from a few hours ago. At the bottom, Opera open and up to date right now.

Given that the absolute number of points haven't changed between this morning and now I don't think that it's the case that I inadvertently clicked on it (and it dropped to 0, then crept up to 368) so I'm mildly curious to know how the recent rep changes counter can decrease so dramatically?

Did some automated job clear out a large percentage (but not all) of the logged recent achievement scores?

---

Edit 2020-04-24 more bizarreness, it has now increased to 4954 (I've reset it several times in the interim) - I thought "oh, maybe someone saw this post and fixed it" but then it's kinda odd because the rep now 27515 minus the rep then 23964 is 3551 so even if I hadn't done a reset between now and then the new counter of 4954 cannot be explained by 3551 nor 3551 + 358..:

[image]

Comment: I had a similar change but in the opposite direction. Mine went from +100 to +535.

Comment: Happened to me too, good I didn't create a duplicate question here, well I guess I will leave my SS here https://imgur.com/a/rpSPG5a in case it helps the bug hunters to hunt down this bug

Comment: I randomly got a +15 around that time, but I couldn't g give anything that it could be attributed to. There were no entries in the list.

Comment: In my case it showed +5 but I got +20 . https://imgur.com/Lyef6Ib

Comment: Mine dropped to 780, from 2000.

Comment: And now it just shot up from ~75 to 4954

Comment: I have a difference of 2227.. no clue.. it’s supposed to be 670 but showing 2897 :)